# Pandas dataframe, a cumsum calculation including max function

Tags: pandas, dataframe, max, cumsum

I'm sitting with a pandas dataframe and I have a time series problem where I have some values called diff. I need to calculate a value, here called sum, according to the below formula for each category separately:

sum<sub>n</sub> = max(0, diff<sub>n</sub> + sum<sub>n-1</sub> - factor)

factor = 2 (factor is a parameter and in this example set to 2)

The dataframe looks something like this and the value of sum is set to 0 for hour = 0:

| category | hour | diff | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| a | 1 | 4 | NaN |
| a | 2 | 3 | NaN |
| a | 3 | 1 | NaN |
| b | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| b | 1 | 1 | NaN |
| b | 2 | -5 | NaN |
| b | 3 | 4 | NaN |

My expected output is the following:

| category | hour | diff | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| a | 1 | 4 | 2 |
| a | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| a | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| b | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| b | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| b | 2 | -5 | 0 |
| b | 3 | 4 | 2 |

Any idea how to solve this? Preferably without iterrows or any for loops since there are a lot of rows.

Would be happy for any help here.

If it would have been without the max function I could have used something like this:

```
df['sum'] = df.groupby(['category'])['diff'].cumsum() - factor
```

But the max function messes things up for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following lambda function:

```
sumn = 0
def calc_sum(df):
    global sumn
    if not df['hour']: # Reset when hour=0
        sumn = 0
    sumn = max(0, df['diff'] + sumn - 2)
    return sumn

df['sum'] = df.groupby(['category']).apply(lambda df: df.apply(calc_sum, axis=1)).values
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, I was a bit unclear but the calculation needs to be done for the two categories independently. And with that function the sum is across the categories.

Comment: @golusp I updated my answer, is that ok now?

Comment: Not really, it does not reset the sumn for the next category. But I fixed that with adding a check of the hour, when 0 sumn is reset to 0. So I have a working solution now. Thanks for guiding me in the right direction.

Comment: @golusp I updated my answer with the reset functionality. Is an accepted answer?